# How can I create a flextable without a row with long format data?

Tags: r, flextable

I have a huge data table in the long format. For each table_id I would subset the data and make a flextable. Using tabulator() is perfect for 90% of my use case but in some of the data, there are no rows which tabulator() requires. Here's a quick example using nonsense dummy data to demonstrate the problem I'm facing:

```
data_A <- data.frame(
  table_id = rep("A", 4),
  column_header_one = c("Mammal", "Mammal", "Mammal", "Mammal"),
  column_header_two = c("Dog", "Dog", "Cat", "Cat"),
  row_header_one = c("row1", "row1", "row1", "row1"),
  row_header_two = c("row", "row", "row", "row"),
  percentage = runif(4, 0, 100),
  standard_error = runif(4, 0, 10)
)

data_B <- data.frame(
  table_id = rep("B", 2),
  column_header_one = c("Bird", "Bird"),
  column_header_two = c("Parrot", "Pigeon"),
  row_header_one = NA,
  row_header_two = NA,
  percentage = runif(2, 0, 100),
  standard_error = runif(2, 0, 10)
)

df <- rbind(data_A, data_B)
print(df)

modified_data <- tabulator(
  x = data_B,
  rows = ???,
  columns = c("column_header_one", "column_header_two"),
  `Perc` = c("percentage"),
  'Std' = c("standard_error")
)

ft <- as_flextable(modified_data)
```

Goal:

[image]

I'm also open to any alternative strategy where I can use a long format data to create a flextable without a row. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now `tabulator()` expect a row dimension. So the trick is to create a dummy one and delete the corresponding column later.

I had to modify `data_A`. There were 2 rows for dog and two rows for cat, it should be 1 row so that only one row is presented.

```
library(flextable)
data_A <- data.frame(
  table_id = rep("A", 2),
  column_header_one = c("Mammal", "Mammal"),
  column_header_two = c("Dog", "Cat"),
  percentage = runif(2, 0, 100),
  standard_error = runif(2, 0, 10)
)

data_B <- data.frame(
  table_id = rep("B", 2),
  column_header_one = c("Bird", "Bird"),
  column_header_two = c("Parrot", "Pigeon"),
  percentage = runif(2, 0, 100),
  standard_error = runif(2, 0, 10)
)
df <- rbind(data_A, data_B)
```

let's create a dummy row that will be deleted later

```
df$dymmy_row <- "dummy"
```

rows and columns counts must all be = 1, you can use count() to check that.

```
dplyr::count(df, dymmy_row, column_header_one, column_header_two)
```

It is now possible to use `tabulator()`.

```
modified_data <- tabulator(
  x = df,
  rows = "dymmy_row",
  columns = c("column_header_one", "column_header_two"),
  `Perc` = as_paragraph(percentage),
  'Std' = as_paragraph(standard_error)
)
```

`sep_w` is set to 0 as we need that to avoid breaks with `merge_h()` that will be used later.

```
ft <- as_flextable(
  modified_data, 
  sep_w = 0 # 
)
ft
```

[image]

Now the final table:

```
delete_columns(ft, 1) |> # delete the dummy row
  merge_h(part = "header") # redo that span instructions that are deleted by `delete_columns()`
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly, you want to use tabulator() to create a flextable even when there are no rows for a particular table_id. In your example, data_B has no rows for table_id "B", and you want to create a flextable for it as well.

You can achieve this by adding a dummy row to your data for each unique table_id before calling tabulator(). This ensures that there is at least one row for each table_id, allowing tabulator() to create a flextable.

Here's an example of how you can modify your code to achieve this:

```
library(flextable)
library(dplyr)

# Function to create a dummy row for each unique table_id
create_dummy_row <- function(data) {
  unique_ids <- unique(data$table_id)
  dummy_rows <- data.frame(table_id = rep(unique_ids, each = 1),
                           stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  return(dummy_rows)
}

# Combine original data with dummy rows
df_with_dummy <- bind_rows(df, create_dummy_row(df))

# Use tabulator() to create flextable
modified_data <- tabulator(
  x = df_with_dummy,
  rows = ???,  # You may need to adjust this based on your actual data
  columns = c("column_header_one", "column_header_two"),
  `Perc` = c("percentage"),
  'Std' = c("standard_error")
)

# Create flextable
ft <- as_flextable(modified_data)
print(ft)
```

This code adds a dummy row for each unique table_id to the original data, and then tabulator() is called on the combined data. Make sure to adjust the rows argument in tabulator() based on your actual data structure. This approach should allow you to create a flextable even when there are no rows for a specific table_id.